# Moleculer custom metrics not exported when running inside container

Tags: prometheus, metrics, moleculer

I'm using moleculer with prometheus reporter and I have a strange situation.
I created a simple service that export a custom metric like so:

```
created() {
    this.broker.metrics.register({
        type: "gauge",
        name: "firebase_push_total",
        description: "Number of successful notifications",
        unit: "notification",
        rate: true // calculate 1-minute rate
    });
},
```

And I increment this value when hitting an end point like so:

```
this.broker.metrics.increment("firebase_push_total",1);
```

the metrics are exported at http://localhost:3030/metrics and I can reach them.

When I run the project with `npm run dev` on my dev machine the metrics are exported and I can see them

```
# HELP firebase_push_total Number of successful notifications
# TYPE firebase_push_total gauge
firebase_push_total{namespace="AKWA-PROD",nodeID="dsi-azza-34756"} 1
firebase_push_total_rate{namespace="AKWA-PROD",nodeID="dsi-azza-34756"} 5.9988002399520095
```

But when I run the code inside the container `(npm run dc:up)` there are only default metrics but the custom ones don't appear.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please create a repro repo.